# Read the output of Process from Cipher command

Tags: vb.net, process

Reading output from process works fine, but it is not able to read "dots" from this command:
cmd /c cipher w:c:

```
With startInfo
    .FileName = "cmd"
    .Arguments = "/c cipher w:c:"
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .RedirectStandardError = True
    .CreateNoWindow = True
    .UseShellExecute = False
End With

AddHandler Proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Proc_OutputDataReceived
Proc.StartInfo = startInfo
Proc.Start()
Proc.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

[Cipher image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P66ZY.png)

Only after the thread has ended it displays the whole messages.
What did I forget?

Comment: What confuses me with this question is why `.FileName` isn't `"cipher"` and why `.Arguments` isn't `"w:c:"`. Why involve the additional task of launching cmd.exe, only to have it run cipher.exe that you could have done directly. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: I tried it too, doesn't work.

Comment: Does `"""w:c:"""` work for the arguments?

Comment: Also, the example I saw online for this command has `cipher /w:c:` - are you sure you don't need the `/`?

Comment: It works but shows the dots at the end of the thread.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue here?

Comment: I spent a lot of time but I did not succeed. The issue is not from the command. I corrected it.

Comment: The comand literally outputs dots...